# First config, Iot Device Connection String field never shows up in Az3166 network connect

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management, iot-devkit, mxchip

Attempting to get the basics going with my Az3166 IoT DevKit, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-get-started.

When I configure the networking for the board, the ***Iot Device Connection String*** field never shows up.  Re-ran it a few times to verify.  Without that string, the board cannot connect to IoT hub.

Help.

*Image of what I'm getting on config*

[image]

**Image from tutorial for what I want**

[image]

Comment: Did you verify with chrome dev tools that the field isn't there and simply hidden due to your browser resolution ?

Comment: I have the same issue and the page source code doesn't contain any connectionstring input control

Comment: I get the same thing, I wonder if they changed how it worked after a recent firmware version